# Sum and product of numbers Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, sum

Hey guys i need to create a program that will display the sum and product of three numbers entered in by the user. I was given code but im not sure what i need to enter in.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Week 3 - Exercise 3-2</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var str1, str2, str3;               //global variables created
        function threeParameters(a,b,c)     //function receives 3 parameters
        {   str1=a;                         //assign 1st parameter to str1
            str2=b;                         //assign 2nd parameter to str2
            str3=c;                         //assign 3rd parameter to str3
            alert(enter code here);     //display the 3 values
            alert(enter coder here);    //display the 3 values
            ver 3 lines
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload = "threeParameters('Hello','out','there1')"> <!--Use the onload event -->
</body>
```

Apparently i need to enter code next to where it says "alert"

Comment: This is all the code i was given. I am not sure if i have to use some of the code and make a whole you program or just enter in the alert area.

Comment: But...the function is currently called with three strings (words) rather than three numbers, and the variable names str1, str2 and str3 imply that the person who wrote that template expects strings rather than numbers. Are you sure you've got the right starting template for the number sum/product exercise?

Comment: I think this is just an example of code i will need to use. I am pretty sure that you can change it around to make it work.

Comment: Despite the "template code" you have being for strings. It's quite basic to add and multiply variables. You simply use `+` for addition (`a+b+c`) and `*` for multiplication (`a*b*c`).

Comment: am i able to add you guys on like skype or something so it would be easier to talk?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not much clear.Is this you want?

```
function threeParameters(a,b,c){      
    alert(a+b+c);
    alert(a*b*c);
 }
```